# Plotting minute data for a year, but only showing beginning of the month on x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, timestamp

I have three datasets, each with a year's worth of data points with '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' format timestamps.

The number of values per day and month vary within the dataset and between the datasets.
Example:

- dataset 1:
  2021-01-01 17:38:00, 200.45

  2021-01-01 20:24:00, 202.59

  2021-01-02 00:03:00, 204.62
- dataset 2:
  2021-01-01 17:49:00, 208.99

  2021-01-01 18:39:00, 203.87

  2021-01-01 21:01:00, 206.47

  2021-01-01 21:35:00, 209.96

  2021-01-02 03:31:00, 204.76

I want to plot the data for each datatset such that on x axis it only shows the beginning of the month. I want to overlay the three graphs to see if they start showing the same upward/downward trend at the same time.

So far I have issue getting pyplot to correctly plot monthly ticks only:

```
locator = md.MonthLocator() 
fmt = md.DateFormatter('%b')
plt.plot(times,data)
X = plt.gca().xaxis
X.set_major_locator(locator)
X.set_major_formatter(fmt)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It looks to me like the graph is showing exactly what you want it to show, all ticks are month names abbreviated.

Comment: The data on the graph is for one year, the ticks go from jan-dec several times.

Comment: I might have misunderstood your premise: you have data from three different years, but you want to overlay all three of those years in the same graph? In that case, there are complex workarounds, or you simply offset all your data to start in the same year and go about the plot as you did here, without showing year labels.

Comment: no, I have data from the same year, but three different locations of measurement. So each location reports back the measured values at different times, but also the frequency of measurement varies between them.
Sorry if I have worded the issue a bit clumsily.

Comment: Ok, so then I see you are plotting `plt.plot(times, data)`. What's your times object? This is your x-data and that's ultimately causing pyplot to think there's data spanning many years. If you can post a minimal reproducible code sample, i.e. some code that someone else can just copy paste and run, that would most helpful.